# How to get all opened tabs session Storage in browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my project i need get when open my project i want t get all opened session storage for current browser.

I have tried like this but it gives current tab session storage

```
console.log(sessionStorage);
```

Comment: It *sounds like* you want to read `window.sessionStorage` from all open **browser** tabs, but you haven't provided any additional context. Please describe what exactly it is you're trying to do and include code from any attempted solutions.

Comment: Please give some more details. Are you using session storage service? If not whats the key value of the storage ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to get all `sessionStorage` objects for all the browser tabs that are opened. If that is the case, you cannot do that: `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` are both subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_data_storage_access) based on the host (even though `a.domain.com` [can access](http://htmlui.com/blog/2011-08-23-5-obscure-facts-about-html5-localstorage.html) `b.domain.com` storage object on some cases, that's largely frowned upon and [should not generally be done](https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/#disk-space)).

If what you are looking for is a way to share data between multiple tabs of your own domain, use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) instead of `sessionStorage`.

Comment: It is possible to [access `localStorage` across domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript) using `window.postMessage`.